# Warwick and Olaf ultis!

Tags: league-of-legends

Warwick and Olaf fighting up top 1v1 like normal. Lets say Warwick ulti's and then immediatly after olaf ultis, but olaf doesn't run away and stays where he was supressed and continues to beat on warwick.

Now, will Warwick ulti proceed to full time or will it stop?

I think I've seen it where Olaf runs and warwick continues to ulti to about where warwick's Q range at. Warwick just keeps slashing the air, but i'm not sure if olaf is taking damage.

Answer (score 1):

Olaf's ultimate (Ragnorak) will cancel Warwick's ultimate (Infinite Duress) entirely. However, there has been a bug in the past which would cause Warwick himself to remain channeling even if his ultimate had been canceled.

Warwick's Ultimate was made more consistent in the [1.0.0.123](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=4674882) and [1.0.0.126](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=351865) patches.

**From v1.0.0.123**

- Fixed a bug where Infinite Duress could sometimes break early even if
  not interrupted

**From v1.0.0.126**

- Infinite Duress will now stop channeling if the target becomes a zombie

Answer (score 0):

Olaf's ult doesnt break the suppress.

Answer (score 0):

Olaf can actually ulti while warwick is flying through the air, and it will in fact stop the supression. However warwick will still go through the animation, scratching the air. Olaf will not take damage.